# Entity framework 6 async/await fail in parallel request

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, async-await, dbcontext

I'm working in ASP.NET 4.6 with EF 6 to a new Web Api 2 project, I've read a lot of articles that describes the async/await pattern and It's clear that for a lot of requests this pattern increase performance for a lot of reasons.
So I decided to use it for the first time.
In decided to create a Biz project and a DAL project here an example.

This is controller method:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<bool> CheckValueValidity(string value, string type)
{
   return await _accountsBiz.CheckValueTypeValidity(value, type);
}
```

I instance biz object in controller constructor.

This is the BIZ:

```
public async Task<bool> CheckValueTypeValidity(string value, string type)
    {
        bool isValid = false;
        switch (type.ToLower())
        {
            case "email":
                isValid = await _accountsRepository.CheckEmailValidity(value);
                break;
            case "username":
                isValid = await _accountsRepository.CheckUserNameValidity(value);
                break;
        }
        return isValid;
    }
```

I instance the repository in the BIZ constructor.

Finally this is the DAL method:

```
public async Task<bool> CheckEmailValidity(string email)
    {
        using(MyEntities db = new MyEntities())
        {
            return await db.AspNetUsers.CountAsync(u => u.Email == email) > 0 ? false : true;
        }
    }
```

And all it seems to work perfectly until I made two request at same time, one of these return the correct value the other say

> A second operation started on this context before a previous asynchronous operation completed. Use 'await' to ensure that any asynchronous operations have completed before calling another method on this context. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.

I made the requests from two different client so the context should be different. should....

I don't know how to fix it. I read a lot and my code seems to be correct.

The question is WHY throw this error? I can't understand

Thanks for help in advice.

Answer (score 0):

Ok found the error in the execution flow there is a method that use `DbContext` without `using` block.... My mistake but now it's clear that context must be disposed each request!